# Swift 2.0 Error: warning: could not load any Objective-C class information

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm getting this error:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information

also

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x7fff5588dfb8)

...when assigning this class:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


class CERangeSliderKnobLayer: CALayer {

    var highlighted = false
    weak var slider = CERangeSlider()

}
```

To a variable like so:

```
import UIKit

    class CERangeSlider: UIControl {

        /*
        // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
        // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            // Drawing code
        }
        */
        var maximumValue = CGFloat()
        var minimumValue = CGFloat()
        var upperValue = CGFloat()
        var lowerValue = CGFloat()

        var trackLayer = CERangeSliderKnobLayer()
        var upperKnobLayer = CERangeSliderKnobLayer()
        var lowerKnobLayer = CERangeSliderKnobLayer()

    ...
    }
```

This makes no sense. There's absolutely no Objective C anywhere in my project that I'm aware of. It's all Swift.

**UPDATE**

If you don't initialize them like that and instead write them like so, i.e.

```
var trackLayer: CERangeSliderKnobLayer!
```

Then you get an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on something like:

```
trackLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the answer was to change my class so that the weak property was not initialized:

```
import QuartzCore


class CERangeSliderKnobLayer: CALayer {

    var highlighted = false
    weak var slider: CERangeSlider!

}
```